# How to write a query to display values only if the condition is met?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(OA.ATHLETE_NAME) AS 'Number of athletes', 
    OG.GAMES_YEAR 
FROM 
    [Olympics].[Events_Facts] AS OEF 
JOIN 
    [Olympics].[Games]  AS OG ON OEF.GAMES_ID = OG.GAMES_ID
JOIN 
    [Olympics].[Athletes] AS OA ON OEF.ATHLETE_ID = OA.ATHLETE_ID
GROUP BY 
    OG.GAMES_YEAR
```

I want to specify in my query, that if an athlete is from Germany display only the participations after 1991 Olympic Games.

Comment: Using a `where` clause?

Comment: in `where` clause i can't write something like: if country = germany then dispaly greater then 1991

Comment: Please illustrate with sample data and desired results, see a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want all participants of all games _except_ for games where there was a participant from Germany, and for games which had somebody from Germany, only display participants after 1991 games? As in, you want a single result set, but the 1991 condition only applies to games with a participant from Germany?

Comment: @brandon , that's exactly what i need. a single result set with the condition above met.

Comment: you can write something like `where country <> 'germany' or year >= 1991`

Comment: @derpirscher, that will not return participants from germany, and i need to display them but only after 1991

Comment: @derpirscher That may not work because _any_ participant in a game being from Germany limits all participants of the corresponding game to > 1991, not just German participants.

Comment: @Brandon I am simply trying to exclude german participants before 1991.

Comment: As I understand the question "*that if an athlete is from Germany display only the participations after 1991 Olympic Games*" it should for Germans only count participations after 1991, and for all others count all participations. If that's not what op needs, we need better explanation and an example would be really helpful

Comment: Then @derpirscher 's suggestion should work.

Comment: @aby_g that condition is equal to `(country = Germany and year > 1991) or country <> Germany` which should exactly do what you want

Comment: @derpirscher i finally understood the meaning of your expression, it works, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(OA.ATHLETE_NAME) AS 'Number of athletes', 
    OG.GAMES_YEAR 
FROM 
    [Olympics].[Events_Facts] AS OEF 
JOIN 
    [Olympics].[Games]  AS OG ON OEF.GAMES_ID = OG.GAMES_ID
JOIN 
    [Olympics].[Athletes] AS OA ON OEF.ATHLETE_ID = OA.ATHLETE_ID
WHERE 
    OA.FROM_COUNTRY = 'Germany' and OG.GAMES_YEAR > 1991
GROUP BY 
    OG.GAMES_YEAR   
    
union all 

SELECT 
    COUNT(OA.ATHLETE_NAME) AS 'Number of athletes', 
    OG.GAMES_YEAR 
FROM 
    [Olympics].[Events_Facts] AS OEF 
JOIN 
    [Olympics].[Games]  AS OG ON OEF.GAMES_ID = OG.GAMES_ID
JOIN 
    [Olympics].[Athletes] AS OA ON OEF.ATHLETE_ID = OA.ATHLETE_ID
WHERE 
    OA.FROM_COUNTRY <> 'Germany'
GROUP BY 
    OG.GAMES_YEAR
```

By using the `OR` command, we can write this query more simply without using the `UNION ALL` command. But `OR` is not recommended by performance.

Comment: how do you measure performance in SSMS?

Comment: `But OR is not recommended by performance.` That is very often true, but I'm skeptical of it as general advice. In fact, in this situation specifically, I'd suggest measuring both ways. The reason being that the baseline query has no `where` clause to begin with, so the query plan likely uses a full table scan. `or` impacts performance in that it makes it harder to use an index, but if we are already looking at a full table scan, there may be 0 cost to the `or`.

I do prefer your version from a readability standpoint.

Comment: @Brandon But if there is an index `(FROM_COUNTRY, GAMES_YEAR)` and the baseline query is the `OR` version, the `UNION ALL` is highly likely to be faster. Yes, the original is doing a full scan, but that wants all results. It's not relevant to the performance question, the only thing you should look at is which query gets *these* results

Comment: @Aby_g `SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;` is a good start. You can also use `Include Client Statistics` button